# Combine Angular 2 application server and REST server modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I am creating a new Angular 4 application. I have followed it's official tutorial https://angular.io/tutorial/

The application server is started using `ng serve` command.

I have created a separate node js (+express) server that provides the REST services to the main app on a different port.

Is there any way to serve the main angular application from the same nodejs/express server so that i don't have to use two servers for the application?

I have used typescript which needs to be somehow compiled into plain javascript before statically being served via nodejs, if i understand it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely, just use ng build and serve the dist folder of the built application, or even the src. Example:

```
const staticFor = rel => express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, rel));
const app = express();
if (!config.production) {
    app.use('/node_modules', staticFor('../node_modules'));
    // In development we do not copy the files over, so map used path
}

app.use('/', staticFor('../dist/app'));
const appPath = path.resolve(
    __dirname,
    config.production ? '../dist/app/index.html' : '../src/app/index.html'
);

app.get('/yourAppPath/*', (req, res) => {
    const markup = fs.readFileSync(appPath, 'utf8');
    res.send(markup);
});
```

Dont forget to require the right libraries.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i was looking for!